# Creating own service (not copying from some other package)

Tags: ros, rosservice, server, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

So I am new to ROS and I went through most of the beginner tutorials. I am at the point where I am learning how to create my own services. In the ROS tutorial on the link below, they tell you how to copy a service from some other package, using 'roscp'.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_srv

A few questions come to mind after following the tutorial on the link above, and the subsequent 2-3 tutorials:

1. **How do I create my OWN service?** This **tutorial shows how to copy one** from some other package. Any **steps that I can follow** to create my own service with my own choice of messages?
2. Can anyone tell me **how the client-server model works with the services?** Its hard to understand what's going on without namespaces in the tutorial. A step-by-step description of what exactly is going on, would be really helpful.
3. This is not an essential piece of knowledge, but I am just curious about why there exist two commands **rosservice** and **rossrv**. **Can't the functionality of both these commands be captured into one, say 'rosservice' only?**
4. In the tutorial link above, they use the function **advertiseService()** with the nodehandle pointer. **Is this a new addition to ROS?** I remember seeing something like advertise() which does the same thing as advertiseService() on some other tutorial page.

Thanks for the patience to go through my post!

Nishant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36089/creating-own-service-(not-copying-from-some-other-package)/) by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on 2012-06-08**:
Thanks Lindzey and joq for your insights! Especially for (1) and (4). I will post a new question if I have
any further doubts! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Rather than using roscp as shown in section 1.5 of the tutorial you linked, create a my_service.srv file in the srv directory. Edit this file to have the fields you want, using the format described (request fields above the ---, response fields below the ---). So long as your CMakeLists.txt file includes the line:

   rosbuild_gensrv()
   all the services defined in the package's srv directory will be made.
2. A service invocation is basically a remote procedure call. The caller (normally) waits until the response is available.
3. I see the distinction between rosservice/rossrv (and rostopic/rosmsg) being that rosservice provides you with tools to analyze and interact with the services in your currently-running system, while rossrv only deals with what's defined in the code.
4. advertise() is for topics, advertiseService() is for services.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-08**:
2)  A service invocation is basically a remote procedure call. The caller (normally) waits until the response is available.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-08**:
4) advertise() is for topics, advertiseService() is for services.

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2012-06-08**:
@joq - I updated the answer with your comments & made it a wiki ... let me know if this isn't the preferred way to handle questions like this!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-08**:
That's fine. I would have felt presumptuous editing your answer myself. :-)